# How to work with "/" using sed in shell script

Tags: regex, macos, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to replace a line in my .xml file using a shell script (working on MAC OSX). Problem is: I want to change a tag `<source-path>/Users/myouser</source-path>` to `<source-path>/Users/otherUser</source-path>`I am having two problems:

1) How can I handle with "/" using sed?
2) Can I use regular expression?

Thanks

Comment: To figure a literal slash with sed: the slash is not a special character, you need to escape it if you use it as delimiter: `s/pat\/pat/repl/`, but you can choose an other delimiter: `s#pat/pat#repl#` (in this case, no need to escape it). About xml parsing, using sed is not the best way and is error prone, try to find a tool to manipulate xml (or use a script language).

Comment: thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answers is to use a different delimiter in your expression, e.g.:

```
sed -e 's|/Users/myouser|/Users/otherUser|' file.xml
```

As to whether you can use regular expressions -- you're using `sed`, so yes.

Standard disclaimer that modifying XML with sed is a fragile and error-prone approach.